# Jquery to rotate an image?

Tags: jquery

I have a meter that looks like this:

[image]

I can keep the shades of blue the same, so all I will need to do is have the Red Arrow rotate from 0% to whatever the percentage I get out of my JSON file.

Is there a simple Jquery plugin that will do this, I need it in IE7-IE8 as well.

I've found similar plug-ins but none seem to work in IE.

Thanks!

Comment: You can try via CSS3 but it won't work in less then IE9. For Jquery, se answer below.
http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_2dtransforms.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery rotate : http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/
It currently supports

1. Internet Explorer 6.0 >
2. Firefox 2.0 >
3. Safari 3 >
4. Opera 9 >
5. Google Chrome

It really is simple to use :

```
$("#img").rotate(45);
```

You can find more info on the WIKI : http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Examples